# incorrect output while reading words from a file using bash script

Tags: bash

I am learning bash scripting and I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        echo "word = '$word'"
    done
done <"words.txt"
```

and here are the contents of words.txt

```
ddddd g
eeee fffffff
```

Here is the output:

```
word = 'ddddd'
'ord = 'g
word = 'eeee'
'ord = 'fffffff
```

What is going on with the output on line 2 and 4? Why is it not print word = 'g' ?

I am using cmder-mini on windows.

thank you.

Comment: Your input file likely is CRLF encoded from windows (so newlines are `\r\n`). While `read line` is going to split out the `\n` parts, when you append `\r` you are really moving the cursor to the start of the string. So you have `word = 'g`, then `\r` takes you to the start, and you finish the output with `'` (overwriting `w`) for a final result of `'ord = 'g`. You only see it every other line because you have two words per line from the input file.

Comment: Also `sh != bash`

Comment: ok, so what needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: If you have `dos2unix` then run `dos2unix words.txt` before calling your script. Or, `sed -i 's/\r$//' words.txt` if you have GNU `sed`.

Comment: Here is a lot of question about this on SO! Question closed with some duplicates pointing to `tr -d \\r`, `dos2unix`and lot of other answers.